# Are there any distributions such that parameters have multimodal posteriors in Bayesian MCMC?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, mcmc

I want to test a new idea I have for Bayesian MCMC, but it'd only be useful with multimodal posteriors. Are there any examples of such distributions?

For instance, with a gaussian mixture model, of course the distribution itself is multimodal. But if I were to use Bayesian metropolis hastings to find the distribution of the parameters themselves given some data, then each parameter's distribution will be unimodal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Models which have symmetry (i.e. you can exchange some parameters and get the same result) have multimodal posteriors. You might get more interest in this question on stats.stackexchange.com or the Stan user forum.

Comment: By the way, an example of a model which has symmetry is a so-called multilayer perceptron, one kind of neural network. If you permute the hidden units, you get exactly the same output. No doubt there are other examples.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was overthinking this, for sure.